# RestKit Many-to-many Relationship with foreign keys

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have a many-to-many relationship in my model.
When I get my Object from the Server, the relationships are not stored.

If I create the object in my code and add a trip to a participant, every thing is correct.

What am I missing?

Participant JSON:

```
participant: {
    event_id: 500,
    name: "Test",
    participant_id: 7900,
    tripIds: [
        5472,
        5678
    ]
}
```

Trip JSON:

```
trip: {
    participants: [
        7916,
        7900
    ],
    trip_id: 5472,
}
```

Mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping* participantMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Participant" 
inManagedObjectStore:self.rkManagedObjectStore];
[participantMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                       @"participant_id": @"participantId",
                                                       @"name": @"name",
                                                       @"event_id": @"eventId",
                                                       @"tripIds":@"tripIds",
                                                       @"days":@"days"                                                           
                                                       }];

participantMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"participantId" ];
[participantMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"event" connectedBy:@"eventId"];


NSEntityDescription *participantEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Participant" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContex];
NSRelationshipDescription *trips = [participantEntity relationshipsByName][@"participatedTrips"]; 
RKConnectionDescription *tripConnection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:trips attributes:@{ @"tripIds": @"tripId" }];


[participantMapping addConnection:tripConnection];


RKEntityMapping* tripMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Trip" inManagedObjectStore:self.rkManagedObjectStore];
    [tripMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                      @"trip_id":@"tripId",
                                                      @"participants":@"participantIds"
                                                      }];
    tripMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"tripId" ];



    NSEntityDescription *tripEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Trip" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContex];
    NSRelationshipDescription *participants = [tripEntity relationshipsByName][@"participants"]; // To many relationship for the `User` entity
    RKConnectionDescription *connection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:participants attributes:@{ @"participantIds": @"participantId" }];


    [tripMapping addConnection:connection];
```

Print Object: (Object from CoreData, eventId is transient)

```
(lldb) po participant
<Participant: 0xaf8a080> (entity: Participant; id: 0xaf8a390 <x-coredata://CFFD7472-B4AF-40BD-9E69-756BC26EB021/Participant/p79> ; data: {
    days = "(\n    4,\n    0\n)";
    event = "0xaf8dc70 <x-coredata://CFFD7472-B4AF-40BD-9E69-756BC26EB021/Event/p3>";
    eventId = 0;
    name = Test;
    participantId = 7900;
    participatedTrips = "<relationship fault: 0xafe6340 'participatedTrips'>";
    tripIds = "(\n    5472,\n    5678\n)";
})
```

Comment: So you're running a request for trips and then for participants? Turn on trace logging (upload the second request log). If you fetch all objects and log the relationship contents they are all empty?